# HERE Map Turn By Turn Activate

Tags: android, navigation, here-api

i'm developing turn by turn based navigation application on android. I'm using HERE maps sdk for android. I can't switch to navigation driver mode for turn by turn navigation. How can i switch normal map to turn by turn mode. 
Note: I changed to map scheme mode 
map.setMapScheme(Map.Scheme.CARNAV_TRAFFIC_DAY);

```
public class BasicMapActivity extends Activity {

    // permissions request code
    private final static int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 1;

    private PositioningManager posManager;

    private MapRoute mapRoute;

    private Route route;

    private GeoPosition myPosition;
    /**
     * Permissions that need to be explicitly requested from end user.
     */
    private static final String[] REQUIRED_SDK_PERMISSIONS = new String[] {
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE };

    // map embedded in the map fragment
    private Map map = null;

    // map fragment embedded in this activity
    private MapFragment mapFragment = null;
    private PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener positionListener = new PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPositionUpdated(PositioningManager.LocationMethod locationMethod, GeoPosition geoPosition, boolean b) {
            Log.v("HERE MAP",geoPosition.getCoordinate().toString());
            myPosition = geoPosition;
            map.setCenter(geoPosition.getCoordinate(),
                    Map.Animation.BOW);
            // Set the zoom level to the average between min and max
        }

        @Override
        public void onPositionFixChanged(PositioningManager.LocationMethod locationMethod, PositioningManager.LocationStatus locationStatus) {

        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        checkPermissions();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (posManager != null) {
            posManager.start(
                    PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (posManager != null) {
            posManager.stop();
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        if (posManager != null) {
            // Cleanup
            posManager.removeListener(
                    positionListener);
        }
        map = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.btnDrawRoute).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawRoute();
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.btnChangeMap).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                setNavigationManager();

                NavigationManager.Error error = NavigationManager.getInstance().startNavigation(route);

                if(error.equals(NavigationManager.Error.NONE)){
                    map.setExtrudedBuildingsVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });

        // Search for the map fragment to finish setup by calling init().
        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);
        mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(OnEngineInitListener.Error error) {
                if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {
                    // retrieve a reference of the map from the map fragment
                    map = mapFragment.getMap();
                    // Set the map center to the Vancouver region (no animation)
                    map.setZoomLevel((map.getMaxZoomLevel() + map.getMinZoomLevel()) / 2);
                    map.setCartoMarkersVisible(true);
                    map.setLandmarksVisible(true);
                    map.setMapScheme(Map.Scheme.CARNAV_DAY);
                    map.setTrafficInfoVisible(true);
                    map.setExtrudedBuildingsVisible(true);
                    map.setStreetLevelCoverageVisible(true);
                    mapFragment.getPositionIndicator().setVisible(true);

                    try {
                        posManager = PositioningManager.getInstance();
                        posManager.addListener(new WeakReference<>(positionListener));
                        posManager.start(
                                PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK);

                    }catch (Exception ex){
                        Log.v("Error",ex.getMessage());
                    }

                } else {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setNavigationManager() {
        NavigationManager.getInstance().setMap(map);
        NavigationManager.getInstance().setMapUpdateMode(NavigationManager.MapUpdateMode.ROADVIEW);
        NavigationManager.getInstance().setTrafficAvoidanceMode(NavigationManager.TrafficAvoidanceMode.DYNAMIC);
        NavigationManager.getInstance().setRealisticViewMode(NavigationManager.RealisticViewMode.DAY);
        NavigationManager.getInstance().setDistanceUnit(NavigationManager.UnitSystem.METRIC);
        ArrayList<NavigationManager.NaturalGuidanceMode> arrayList = new ArrayList<NavigationManager.NaturalGuidanceMode>();
        arrayList.add(NavigationManager.NaturalGuidanceMode.JUNCTION);
        arrayList.add(NavigationManager.NaturalGuidanceMode.STOP_SIGN);
        arrayList.add(NavigationManager.NaturalGuidanceMode.TRAFFIC_LIGHT);
        EnumSet<NavigationManager.NaturalGuidanceMode> enumSet = EnumSet.copyOf(arrayList);
        NavigationManager.getInstance().setNaturalGuidanceMode(enumSet);

        setVoice();

        ArrayList<NavigationManager.AudioEvent> audioEvents = new ArrayList<>();
        audioEvents.add(NavigationManager.AudioEvent.ROUTE);
        audioEvents.add(NavigationManager.AudioEvent.GPS);
        NavigationManager.getInstance().setEnabledAudioEvents(EnumSet.copyOf(audioEvents));

        NavigationManager.getInstance().addNewInstructionEventListener(new WeakReference<NavigationManager.NewInstructionEventListener>(new NavigationManager.NewInstructionEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNewInstructionEvent() {
                super.onNewInstructionEvent();
                Maneuver maneuver = NavigationManager.getInstance().getNextManeuver();

                Log.v("Manevra",maneuver.getNextRoadName() + " "+maneuver.getRoadName());

                maneuver.getRoadName();
            }
        }));

        NavigationManager.getInstance().addManeuverEventListener(new WeakReference<NavigationManager.ManeuverEventListener>(new NavigationManager.ManeuverEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onManeuverEvent() {
                super.onManeuverEvent();
            }
        }));

        NavigationManager.getInstance().addPositionListener(new WeakReference<NavigationManager.PositionListener>(new NavigationManager.PositionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPositionUpdated(GeoPosition geoPosition) {
                super.onPositionUpdated(geoPosition);
                geoPosition.getCoordinate();
                geoPosition.getHeading();
                geoPosition.getSpeed();

                // also remaining time and distance can be
                // fetched from navigation manager
                NavigationManager.getInstance().getTta(Route.TrafficPenaltyMode.DISABLED, true);
                NavigationManager.getInstance().getDestinationDistance();
            }
        }));
    }

    private void setVoice() {
        // Get the list of voice packages from the voice catalog list
        List<VoicePackage> voicePackages = VoiceCatalog.getInstance().getCatalogList();

        long id = -1;

// select
        for (VoicePackage vPackage : voicePackages) {
            if (vPackage.getMarcCode().compareToIgnoreCase("eng") == 0) {
                if (vPackage.isTts()) {
                    id = vPackage.getId();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if(id>-1)
            NavigationManager.getInstance().setVoiceSkin(VoiceCatalog.getInstance().getLocalVoiceSkin(id));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Checks the dynamically controlled permissions and requests missing permissions from end user.
     */
    protected void checkPermissions() {
        final List<String> missingPermissions = new ArrayList<String>();
        // check all required dynamic permissions
        for (final String permission : REQUIRED_SDK_PERMISSIONS) {
            final int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
            if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                missingPermissions.add(permission);
            }
        }
        if (!missingPermissions.isEmpty()) {
            // request all missing permissions
            final String[] permissions = missingPermissions
                    .toArray(new String[missingPermissions.size()]);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        } else {
            final int[] grantResults = new int[REQUIRED_SDK_PERMISSIONS.length];
            Arrays.fill(grantResults, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            onRequestPermissionsResult(REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS, REQUIRED_SDK_PERMISSIONS,
                    grantResults);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[],
            @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
                for (int index = permissions.length - 1; index >= 0; --index) {
                    if (grantResults[index] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // exit the app if one permission is not granted
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Required permission '" + permissions[index]
                                + "' not granted, exiting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                // all permissions were granted
                initialize();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void drawRoute(){
        CoreRouter router = new CoreRouter();
        GeoCoordinate gebzeCoord = new GeoCoordinate(40.9047617,29.4065243);
        GeoCoordinate maslakCoord = new GeoCoordinate(41.1066509,29.0204711);
        // Create the RoutePlan and add two waypoints
        RoutePlan routePlan = new RoutePlan();
        routePlan.addWaypoint(new RouteWaypoint(myPosition.getCoordinate()));
        routePlan.addWaypoint(new RouteWaypoint(maslakCoord));

        // Create the RouteOptions and set its transport mode & routing type
        RouteOptions routeOptions = new RouteOptions();
        routeOptions.setTransportMode(RouteOptions.TransportMode.CAR);
        routeOptions.setRouteType(RouteOptions.Type.FASTEST);

        routePlan.setRouteOptions(routeOptions);

        // Calculate the route
        router.calculateRoute(routePlan, new RouteListener());

        TrafficUpdater trafficUpdater = TrafficUpdater.getInstance();
        trafficUpdater.request(route, new TrafficUpdater.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(TrafficUpdater.RequestState requestState) {

            }
        });
    }

    private class RouteListener implements CoreRouter.Listener {

        // Method defined in Listener
        public void onProgress(int percentage) {
            // Display a message indicating calculation progress
        }

        // Method defined in Listener
        public void onCalculateRouteFinished(List<RouteResult> routeResult, RoutingError error) {
            // If the route was calculated successfully
            if (error == RoutingError.NONE) {
                // Render the route on the map
                mapRoute = new MapRoute(routeResult.get(0).getRoute());
                route = routeResult.get(0).getRoute();
                map.addMapObject(mapRoute);
            }
            else {
                // Display a message indicating route calculation failure
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show what you have done so far.

Comment: map.setCartoMarkersVisible(true);
                    map.setLandmarksVisible(true);
                    map.setMapScheme(Map.Scheme.CARNAV_DAY);
                    map.setTrafficInfoVisible(true);
                    map.setExtrudedBuildingsVisible(true);
                    map.setStreetLevelCoverageVisible(true);
                    mapFragment.getPositionIndicator().setVisible(true);

Comment: NavigationManager.getInstance().setMap(map);
        NavigationManager.getInstance().setMapUpdateMode(NavigationManager.MapUpdateMode.ROADVIEW);
        NavigationManager.getInstance().setTrafficAvoidanceMode(NavigationManager.TrafficAvoidanceMode.DYNAMIC);
        NavigationManager.getInstance().setRealisticViewMode(NavigationManager.RealisticViewMode.DAY);
        NavigationManager.getInstance().setDistanceUnit(NavigationManager.UnitSystem.METRIC);

Comment: ArrayList<NavigationManager.NaturalGuidanceMode> arrayList = new ArrayList<NavigationManager.NaturalGuidanceMode>();
        arrayList.add(NavigationManager.NaturalGuidanceMode.JUNCTION);
        arrayList.add(NavigationManager.NaturalGuidanceMode.STOP_SIGN);
        arrayList.add(NavigationManager.NaturalGuidanceMode.TRAFFIC_LIGHT);
        EnumSet<NavigationManager.NaturalGuidanceMode> enumSet = EnumSet.copyOf(arrayList);
        NavigationManager.getInstance().setNaturalGuidanceMode(enumSet);

        setVoice();

Comment: ArrayList<NavigationManager.AudioEvent> audioEvents = new ArrayList<>();
        audioEvents.add(NavigationManager.AudioEvent.ROUTE);
        audioEvents.add(NavigationManager.AudioEvent.GPS);
        NavigationManager.getInstance().setEnabledAudioEvents(EnumSet.copyOf(audioEvents));

Comment: NavigationManager.getInstance().addNewInstructionEventListener(new WeakReference<NavigationManager.NewInstructionEventListener>(new NavigationManager.NewInstructionEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNewInstructionEvent() {
                super.onNewInstructionEvent();
                Maneuver maneuver = NavigationManager.getInstance().getNextManeuver();
                
                Log.v("Manevra",maneuver.getNextRoadName() + " "+maneuver.getRoadName());
                
                maneuver.getRoadName();
            }
        }));

Comment: findViewById(R.id.btnChangeMap).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
                setNavigationManager();
                
                NavigationManager.Error error = NavigationManager.getInstance().startNavigation(route);
                
                if(error.equals(NavigationManager.Error.NONE)){
                    map.setExtrudedBuildingsVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });

Comment: dont post in comments. Edit your question and put this stuff there.

Answer (score 0):

Declare **NavigationManager**'s object as a global object.

```
private NavigationManager m_navigationManager;
```

after that initialize it in your `setNavigationManager()` method.

```
m_navigationManager = NavigationManager.getInstance();
m_navigationManager.setMap(map);
// try to change current MapUpdateMode to POSITION_ANIMATION
m_navigationManager.setMapUpdateMode(NavigationManager.MapUpdateMode.POSITION_ANIMATION);
m_navigationManager.setTrafficAvoidanceMode(NavigationManager.TrafficAvoidanceMode.DYNAMIC);
m_navigationManager.setRealisticViewMode(NavigationManager.RealisticViewMode.DAY);
// set all other method on this  object.
m_navigationManager.......
```

After you have to start navigation like this

```
NavigationManager.Error error = m_navigationManager.startNavigation(route);

 if (error != NavigationManager.Error.NONE) {
         m_navigationManager.setMap(null);
 }

//set Tilt to at some angle that you can look in 3d mode
map.setTilt(70f, com.here.android.mpa.mapping.Map.Animation.NONE);
map.setZoomLevel(18);
```

Comment: thanks for reply but still it doesn't shown 3d view navigation driver mode shown 2d view

Comment: @ErsinG try to change current MapUpdateMode to POSITION_ANIMATION. check my edited answer.

Comment: thanks, i figured out the problem i've changed to tilt value and navigation mode changed to 3d view. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ErsinG Glad to help you :)